# Redirect user to login page when they have to access to a view?

Tags: 7, views, redirection

I have a view which is only accessible to authenticated users. However, there are links to it on the site. Can I make it so that an unauthenticated user gets redirected to the login page, instead of the 403 they're seeing now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Redirect 403 to User Login](http://drupal.org/project/r4032login) module should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), it is very configurable and should allow you to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

With [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), the login form can be added to Access Denied (403) pages. No redirects needed.